# Removing attributes from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON tree structure like below using D3. I am saving into Mongo DB but I am trying to remove the unncessary fields like the `x`, `y`, `id`, `xo` and `yo`. I was wondering if there is anyway to do this using any natural d3.js function.

```
{
   "name": "law",
   "children": [
      {
         "name": "criminal",
         "children": [
            {
               "name": "drugs",
               "children": [
                  {
                     "name": "abuse",
                     "depth": 3,
                     "x": 14.5161295,
                     "y": 870,
                     "id": 17,
                     "x0": 14.5161295,
                     "y0": 870,
                     "children": [
                        {
                           "name": "asd",
                           "id": "aa909548-9200-45d6-86e9-f02708bfb70d",
                           "depth": 4,
                           "_children": null,
                           "x": 14.5161295,
                           "y": 1160,
                           "x0": 14.5161295,
                           "y0": 1160
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "trafficking",
                     "depth": 3,
                     "x": 29.032259,
                     "y": 870,
                     "id": 18,
                     "x0": 29.032259,
                     "y0": 870
                  }
               ],
               "depth": 2,
               "x": 21.774193,
               "y": 580,
               "id": 19,
               "x0": 21.774193,
               "y0": 580
            },
            {
               "name": "sexual harrasement",
               "children": [
                  {
                     "name": "harrasement in education",
                     "depth": 3,
                     "x": 58.064518,
                     "y": 870,
                     "id": 15,
                     "x0": 58.064518,
                     "y0": 870
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "harrasement in workplace",
                     "depth": 3,
                     "x": 72.58064,
                     "y": 870,
                     "id": 14,
                     "x0": 72.58064,
                     "y0": 870
                  }
               ],
               "depth": 2,
               "x": 65.32258,
               "y": 580,
               "id": 16,
               "x0": 65.32258,
               "y0": 580
            },
            {
               "name": "violent",
               "children": [
                  {
                     "name": "acts intended to cause injury",
                     "depth": 3,
                     "x": 101.6129,
                     "y": 870,
                     "id": 12,
                     "x0": 101.6129,
                     "y0": 870
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "robbery",
                     "depth": 3,
                     "x": 116.129036,
                     "y": 870,
                     "id": 11,
                     "x0": 116.129036,
                     "y0": 870
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "sexual assault",
                     "depth": 3,
                     "x": 130.64516,
                     "y": 870,
                     "id": 10,
                     "x0": 130.64516,
                     "y0": 870
                  }
               ],
               "depth": 2,
               "x": 116.129036,
               "y": 580,
               "id": 13,
               "x0": 116.129036,
               "y0": 580
            }
         ],
         "depth": 1,
         "x": 68.951614,
         "y": 290,
         "id": 20,
         "x0": 68.951614,
         "y0": 290
      },
      {
         "name": "family",
         "children": [
            {
               "name": "adoption",
               "depth": 2,
               "x": 152.41936,
               "y": 580,
               "id": 2,
               "x0": 152.41936,
               "y0": 580
            },
            {
               "name": "child abuse",
               "depth": 2,
               "x": 166.93549,
               "y": 580,
               "id": 1,
               "x0": 166.93549,
               "y0": 580
            },
            {
               "name": "divorce",
               "children": [
                  {
                     "name": "contested-divorce",
                     "children": [
                        {
                           "name": "mediation",
                           "depth": 4,
                           "x": 152.41936,
                           "y": 1160,
                           "id": 6,
                           "x0": 152.41936,
                           "y0": 1160
                        },
                        {
                           "id": "2.1.1.1",
                           "name": "trial",
                           "depth": 4,
                           "x": 166.93549,
                           "y": 1160,
                           "x0": 166.93549,
                           "y0": 1160
                        }
                     ],
                     "depth": 3,
                     "x": 159.67741,
                     "y": 870,
                     "id": 7,
                     "x0": 159.67741,
                     "y0": 870
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "no-fault divorce",
                     "children": [
                        {
                           "name": "custody",
                           "depth": 4,
                           "x": 195.96774,
                           "y": 1160,
                           "id": 4,
                           "x0": 195.96774,
                           "y0": 1160
                        },
                        {
                           "name": "division of marital assets",
                           "depth": 4,
                           "x": 210.48387,
                           "y": 1160,
                           "id": 3,
                           "x0": 210.48387,
                           "y0": 1160
                        }
                     ],
                     "depth": 3,
                     "x": 203.2258,
                     "y": 870,
                     "id": 5,
                     "x0": 203.2258,
                     "y0": 870
                  }
               ],
               "depth": 2,
               "x": 181.45161,
               "y": 580,
               "id": 8,
               "x0": 181.45161,
               "y0": 580
            }
         ],
         "depth": 1,
         "x": 166.93549,
         "y": 290,
         "id": 9,
         "x0": 166.93549,
         "y0": 290
      }
   ],
   "x0": 117.94355,
   "y0": 0,
   "depth": 0,
   "x": 117.94355,
   "y": 0,
   "id": 21
}
```

Comment: Your D3 code is just loading the JSON file. If you don't want to use those properties, simply leave them there. On the other hand, if you want to save a smaller JSON file without your unused properties, this has nothing to do with D3: remove the D3 tag from this question and add the tag relative to the library/framework/language/whatever that you used to create/save the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I totally agree with Gerardo's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888747/removing-attributes-from-json-d3#comment74814161_43888747) stating that this is neither related to D3 in special nor is D3 a very good choice tackling this problem. As it turns out, this can easily be done in pure JavaScript. Second, although not exactly clear from your question, I suppose you are dealing with an object in literal notation rather than a JSON string.

There are basically two ways to get this done:

1. Recursively step through your tree using the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator to get rid of the properties you do **not** want in your resulting JSON string to be saved. There are various techniques for doing the actual recursion, many of which are extensively covered by similar questions, so I will leave this aside.
2. Since you explicitly asked for the tree to be stored as JSON, you can use the [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) parameter, which can be supplied as the second argument to `JSON.stringify()`:

   > ```
   > JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
   > ```
   >
   > *[…]*
   >
   > **replacer**  | *Optional*
   >
   > A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process, or an array of String and Number objects that serve as a whitelist for **selecting/filtering** the properties of the value object to be included in the JSON string. If this value is null or not provided, all properties of the object are included in the resulting JSON string.

   For this to work, however, you need to specify a whitelist of properties you want to be included in the output. Note, how this is contrary to the deletion of option 1.

   For your case this could be something like this:

   ```
   JSON.stringify(data, ["name", "depth", "children"]);
   ```

   ```js
   var data = {
      "name": "law",
      "children": [
         {
            "name": "criminal",
            "children": [
               {
                  "name": "drugs",
                  "children": [
                     {
                        "name": "abuse",
                        "depth": 3,
                        "x": 14.5161295,
                        "y": 870,
                        "id": 17,
                        "x0": 14.5161295,
                        "y0": 870,
                        "children": [
                           {
                              "name": "asd",
                              "id": "aa909548-9200-45d6-86e9-f02708bfb70d",
                              "depth": 4,
                              "_children": null,
                              "x": 14.5161295,
                              "y": 1160,
                              "x0": 14.5161295,
                              "y0": 1160
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name": "trafficking",
                        "depth": 3,
                        "x": 29.032259,
                        "y": 870,
                        "id": 18,
                        "x0": 29.032259,
                        "y0": 870
                     }
                  ],
                  "depth": 2,
                  "x": 21.774193,
                  "y": 580,
                  "id": 19,
                  "x0": 21.774193,
                  "y0": 580
               },
               {
                  "name": "sexual harrasement",
                  "children": [
                     {
                        "name": "harrasement in education",
                        "depth": 3,
                        "x": 58.064518,
                        "y": 870,
                        "id": 15,
                        "x0": 58.064518,
                        "y0": 870
                     },
                     {
                        "name": "harrasement in workplace",
                        "depth": 3,
                        "x": 72.58064,
                        "y": 870,
                        "id": 14,
                        "x0": 72.58064,
                        "y0": 870
                     }
                  ],
                  "depth": 2,
                  "x": 65.32258,
                  "y": 580,
                  "id": 16,
                  "x0": 65.32258,
                  "y0": 580
               },
               {
                  "name": "violent",
                  "children": [
                     {
                        "name": "acts intended to cause injury",
                        "depth": 3,
                        "x": 101.6129,
                        "y": 870,
                        "id": 12,
                        "x0": 101.6129,
                        "y0": 870
                     },
                     {
                        "name": "robbery",
                        "depth": 3,
                        "x": 116.129036,
                        "y": 870,
                        "id": 11,
                        "x0": 116.129036,
                        "y0": 870
                     },
                     {
                        "name": "sexual assault",
                        "depth": 3,
                        "x": 130.64516,
                        "y": 870,
                        "id": 10,
                        "x0": 130.64516,
                        "y0": 870
                     }
                  ],
                  "depth": 2,
                  "x": 116.129036,
                  "y": 580,
                  "id": 13,
                  "x0": 116.129036,
                  "y0": 580
               }
            ],
            "depth": 1,
            "x": 68.951614,
            "y": 290,
            "id": 20,
            "x0": 68.951614,
            "y0": 290
         },
         {
            "name": "family",
            "children": [
               {
                  "name": "adoption",
                  "depth": 2,
                  "x": 152.41936,
                  "y": 580,
                  "id": 2,
                  "x0": 152.41936,
                  "y0": 580
               },
               {
                  "name": "child abuse",
                  "depth": 2,
                  "x": 166.93549,
                  "y": 580,
                  "id": 1,
                  "x0": 166.93549,
                  "y0": 580
               },
               {
                  "name": "divorce",
                  "children": [
                     {
                        "name": "contested-divorce",
                        "children": [
                           {
                              "name": "mediation",
                              "depth": 4,
                              "x": 152.41936,
                              "y": 1160,
                              "id": 6,
                              "x0": 152.41936,
                              "y0": 1160
                           },
                           {
                              "id": "2.1.1.1",
                              "name": "trial",
                              "depth": 4,
                              "x": 166.93549,
                              "y": 1160,
                              "x0": 166.93549,
                              "y0": 1160
                           }
                        ],
                        "depth": 3,
                        "x": 159.67741,
                        "y": 870,
                        "id": 7,
                        "x0": 159.67741,
                        "y0": 870
                     },
                     {
                        "name": "no-fault divorce",
                        "children": [
                           {
                              "name": "custody",
                              "depth": 4,
                              "x": 195.96774,
                              "y": 1160,
                              "id": 4,
                              "x0": 195.96774,
                              "y0": 1160
                           },
                           {
                              "name": "division of marital assets",
                              "depth": 4,
                              "x": 210.48387,
                              "y": 1160,
                              "id": 3,
                              "x0": 210.48387,
                              "y0": 1160
                           }
                        ],
                        "depth": 3,
                        "x": 203.2258,
                        "y": 870,
                        "id": 5,
                        "x0": 203.2258,
                        "y0": 870
                     }
                  ],
                  "depth": 2,
                  "x": 181.45161,
                  "y": 580,
                  "id": 8,
                  "x0": 181.45161,
                  "y0": 580
               }
            ],
            "depth": 1,
            "x": 166.93549,
            "y": 290,
            "id": 9,
            "x0": 166.93549,
            "y0": 290
         }
      ],
      "x0": 117.94355,
      "y0": 0,
      "depth": 0,
      "x": 117.94355,
      "y": 0,
      "id": 21
   };

   var json = JSON.stringify(data, ["name", "depth", "children"]);
   console.log(json);
   ```